# what causes imagecreatetruecolor() to fail?

Tags: php, gdlib

i am sure that my gdlib is enabled since the `imagecreafromjpeg()` function precedes the part where i call the `imagecreatruecolor()` and there's no error generated from that
however the script breaks on the part (or rather fails with no error message and simply returns false) where `imagecreatruecolor()` is called..

 how can i find the cause of the failure?

```
if ($filetype=='jpg' || $filetype=='jpeg')
    $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($name);      
if ($filetype=='png')
    $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($name);       
if($src_img===false){ return false;}

$orig_w = imageSX($src_img);
$orig_h = imageSY($src_img);
$new_w = ($orig_w > $new_w) ? $new_w : $orig_w;
$new_h = ($orig_h > $new_h) ? $new_h : $orig_h;
$dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_w,$new_h);
```

Comment: Is your error reporting on full blast?

Comment: @havenard okee there's the code

Comment: What were the values of $new_w and $new_h?

Comment: make sure you have error_reporting(E_ALL); somewhere before these lines of code, hopefully it'll show something.

Answer (score 0):

Create a phpinfo-file to check your GD-version. imagecreatetruecolor() is only available in version 2.0.1 or later (they recommend 2.0.28).

Try the "[function_exists('imagecreatetruecolor')](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php)" as well.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. What i did was put the error_report(E_ALL) before my imagecreatetruecolor and found out that it needs more memory. Just upgraded my php.ini to 256mb and its working fine now.